# Composite Index - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, composite-index

The sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats DMV gives information about number of seeks and scans against a index in sql server

I have a large number of composite index that includes multiple columns. I suspect that these indexes cause a lot of maintenance overhead ann would like to narrow the number of columns.

Is there a way we can find out seeks and scans against a indivudual columns in a composite index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQL Server` does not implement `SKIP SCAN`, so a seek over a composite index always includes leftmost (leading) columns of the index.

That is, if you have an index on `(col1, col2)`, the index seek may be used for searching for `col1` or `col1` *and* `col2`, but not for `col2` alone.

If you search for all of these columns, you will most probably benefit from using the index.

What is the "maintenance overhead" you mentioned and how does it differ between single-column and multiple-column indexes?

Comment: Thanks for the input.. it helps..

I have a composite index with file columns like (col1,col2, col3,col4,col5) etc... Can we find how many times all five columns were used in the seek.. how many seeks were against 4 columsn etc..

Again thanks for the input

Comment: `@Dave`: no, you can't tell it from the index usage stats. This is best done by looking at your query execution plans.

Comment: Thanks Quassnoi!.. i need to pull some metrics to on the composite index usage in the server.. to justify thet they need to be narrowed down. I guess that are used my multiple stored procedure in the application.

Comment: The Microsoft Connect item about the skip scan: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/695044/implement-index-skip-scan